# Memory leak on Reactive Cocoa swift 3.0

Tags: swift, cocoa, memory-leaks, swift3, reactive-cocoa

I'm new in Reactive Cocoa for Swift, and trying to make a custom signal for my Web Service calls.
I got memory leak on profiler, however I can't figure out where to dispose the Signal in order to avoid the leaks.

```
public func GetGroups() -> Signal<[GroupModel], SError>? {

        let accToken:String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "access_token")
        let headers = ["Authorization":"Bearer " + accToken!]

        let signal = Signal<[GroupModel],SError>({(obs:Observer<[GroupModel],SError>) -> Disposable?
            in
            Alamofire.request(serverUrl+"/api/group/groups",method:HTTPMethod.get,parameters:nil,encoding:URLEncoding.default,headers:headers)
            .responseArray(completionHandler: {(data:DataResponse<[GroupModel]>) -> Void in

                if data.error != nil{

                   //handle error

                }else{
                    obs.send(value: data.result.value!)
                }


            })
            return nil
        })

        return signal;

    }
```

and this is how i call the service.

```
_ = groupService.GetGroups()?
            .observeResult{
            self.dataSource = $0.value
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should use `SignalProducer` instead of `Signal` to emit network service events.

There are two main issues in your codes.

- In your signal implementation, your `signal` will not completed in future, which means your **observer** will always there, this leads to your memory leak.
- In your observe block (as observer), `self` used directly will be captured in **strong**, as above said that your observer will be there, so that `self` can not be dealloc in a right way.